# Created CSV file with district name, area, capacity, and energy, joined to QGIS project, and loaded shapefile.shp

Tags: attributes, qgis

I have created a CSV file with columns for District Name, Total Area (ha), Total Capacity (MW), and Total Estimated Energy (GWh). I have also successfully joined this CSV data to my QGIS project. Additionally, I have loaded a shapefile named 'district.shp' into QGIS and joined its attributes with the District column from the CSV.

However, when I attempted to symbolize the districts on the map, I encountered an issue. I couldn't find the 'Total Estimated Energy' as an option to classify or use as a value for symbology. Can you please explain why this attribute is not available for classification in QGIS?